# Nested (Apache Tapestry) AjaxFormLoop

Tags: tapestry

I'm developing a webapp using JavaEE and Apache Tapestry framework. The task is to implement a nested AjaxFormLoop component (i.e.: one loop inside another). Here is the issue:

Issue:
I am developing a page which has 4 levels of nested AjaxFormLoop and currently trying to get the 2nd level (which is also the first nested level) to work. Let's call the outer loop "outerLoop" and the inner one "innerLoop". The issue is: I have one dedicated encoder for each "innerLoop" (the encoders also have reference to the actual server side object list). However, I don't have a way to let each "innerLoop" know which encoder is for them.

Questions:

1. Is there a workaround for this or I'm using encoder in a wrong way?
2. Is it possible to implement nested AjaxFormLoop?

More details:

1. My form can successfully load and render from server side objects.
2. When the form was loading, the "innerLoop" can correctly get their own encoders by accessing using "outerLoop"'s "value" variable.
3. After the form was rendered, the "value" variable of "outerLoop" is set to null, and this is where I start to get trouble.
4. When "OnAddRowFromInnerLoop" is invoked, I can figure out which is the "parent outer loop item" as I'm using "t:context", but this doesn't help with encoder.

Please let me know if I should write some code to demo (as the actual code is a bit lengthy) the problem or describe this issue clearer or better.

I've been desperately trying a couple of approaches but stuck with this encoder issue and my work is lagging behind so ALL advices are highly appreciated. Thanks for you time and help in advance!

P.S.: I have posted the same question to tapestry mailing list and will update here wherever I find a solution / conclusion to this.

Yours sincerely,
Bo Wan

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the question by using only one instance of encoder for all inner forms from same level / type . The encoder have access to all objects for the same type and it loops through all lists to search the object when decoding.